# pysimpleaudio left or right channel

Tags: python

[pysimpleaudio](/questions/tagged/pysimpleaudio)
In the function checks, playback is separated into left and right channels.

Is there any way to do this for playing a wav?

Is there a way to put this in the play_obj = wave_obj.play()
as a parameter?

Comment: I can't find anything named `pysimpleaudio` anywhere. There's a [`simpleaudio`](https://pypi.org/project/simpleaudio/) and a [`py-simple-audio`](https://github.com/hamiltron/py-simple-audio/). Are you asking about one of those, or something different?

Comment: Assuming you're asking about the latter, and about the `LeftRightCheck` function, a quick look at [the source](https://github.com/hamiltron/py-simple-audio/blob/master/simpleaudio/functionchecks.py#L52) gives you the answer: that function just plays a wave file named `left_right.wav`, which is presumably a stereo file that has a tone all the way over to the left and then a tone all the way over to the right. So you can't do the same thing.

Comment: You _could_ presumably load a wav file and blank out one channel or the other and play it. Without knowing anything about the library, I can't tell you how easy it is for sure—but if it's not as easy as just a one-line numpy or slice operation, you're probably better off with a different library, because usually it is.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I am referring to the first one. https://github.com/hamiltron/py-simple-audio.

Comment: Actually I think all if these are the same library.

Comment: Re the comment from @abarnert and incorrect tagging: to be fair, the docs for Simpleaudio suggests the tag pysimpleaudio for SO support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here's the source of the `LeftRightCheck` function you're asking about](https://github.com/hamiltron/py-simple-audio/blob/master/simpleaudio/functionchecks.py#L52):

```
class LeftRightCheck(FunctionCheckBase):
    """
    Checks stereo playback by first playing a note in the left channel only,
    then a different note in the right channel only.
    """

    @classmethod
    def _check(cls):
        wave_obj = _gwo("left_right.wav")
        wave_obj.play()
        sleep(4)
```

In other words, it isn't using any undocumented features that you could take advantage of; it's just playing a stereo WAV file in both channels, but that WAV file, `left_right.wav`, has a note in the left channel and then a note in the right channel.

---

But, even though the library doesn't seem to have any feature for playing audio in a single channel, you could presumably just load a WAV file and then blank out one channel or the other and play the result.

This is easy to do in, e.g., the stdlib's `wave` module, and trivial to do with any of the NumPy-based audio modules (e.g., `samples[:,1] = 0`), so I'm sure it's easy to do with this library (or, if it isn't, you probably should be using a better library).